# How to Append attribute by using HtmlAgilitiPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, html

I'm trying to make a new attribute in HTML tag by using HAP library:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(PATH);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input");
nodes[0].Attributes["foo"].Value = "baa"; /* try add 'foo' attribute with 'baa' value in input HTML element. */
doc.Save(@"C:\foo.html");
```

but it wiil get an exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if `nodes` is non-null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes. And .Count is nonzero

The it means the attribute first needs to be created and then added to the collection (as far as I remember since I've last used this lib):

```
HtmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("foo", "baa");
nodes[0].Attributes.Add(attr);
```